# Context API consume from anywhere

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a shared state into my application using the React context api.

I am creating an `errorContext` state at the root of my tree. The error context looks like so:

```
// ErrorContext.js
import React from 'react';
const ErrorContext = React.createContext({
    isError: false,
    setError:   (error) => {}
});

export default ErrorContext;
```

### Desired Result

- I would like to update (consume) this context from anywhere in the app (specifically from within a promise)
- Ideally the consume step should be extracted into a exported helper function

**Example Usage of helper function**

```
http.get('/blah')
    .catch((error) => {
        HelperLibrary.setError(true);
    })
```

### Following the react context docs:

I can create a provider like so :

```
class ProviderClass {
    state = {
        isError: false,
        setError: (error) => {
            this.state.isError = error;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ErrorContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ErrorContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Then I can consume this provider by using the Consumer wrapper from inside a render call:

```
<ErrorContext.Consumer>
    {(context) => {
        context.setError(true); 
    }}
</ErrorContext.Consumer>
```

### The Problem with this approach

This approach would require every developer on my team to write lots of boilerplate code every-time they wish to handle a web service error.

e.g. They would have to place `ErrorContext.Consumer` inside the components `render()` method and render it conditionally depending on the web service response.

### What I have tried

Using ReactDOM.render from within a helper function.

```
const setError = (error) =>{
       ReactDOM.render(
           <ErrorContext.Consumer>
               // boilerplate that i mentioned above
           </ErrorContext.Consumer>,

           document.getElementById('contextNodeInDOM')
       )    }
       export default setError;
```

**Why doesn't this work?**

For some reason ReactDOM.render() always places this code outside the React component tree.

```
<App>
    ...
        <ProviderClass>
            ...
            <div id="contextNodeInDOM'></div> <-- even though my node is here
            ...
        </ProviderClass>
</App>
<ErrorContext.Consumer></ErrorContext.Consumer> <-- ReactDOM.render puts the content here
```

Therefore there is no context parent found for the consumer, so it defaults to the default context (which has no state)

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer)

> If there is no Provider for this context above, the value argument
>   will be equal to the defaultValue that was passed to createContext().

If anyone can assist me on my next step, I am coming from Angular so apologies if my terminology is incorrect or if I am doing something extremely stupid.

Comment: The purpose of context API is to not allow to consume it from anywhere but only inside <Consumer> component, otherwise it won't differ from any application-wide variable. In Angular terms, <Consumer> does DI. You could skip boilerplate code, similarly to how the answer suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export a HOC to wrap the error component before export, eliminating the boilerplate and ensuring that the context is provided only where needed, and without messing with the DOM:

```
// error_context.js(x)
export const withErrorContext = (Component) => {
  return (props) => (
    <ErrorContext.Consumer>
      {context => <Component {...props} errorContext={context} />}
    </ErrorContext.Consumer>
  )
};

// some_component.js(x)
const SomeComponent = ({ errorContext, ...props }) => {
  http.get('/blah')
      .catch((error) => {
        errorContext.setError(true);
      })

  return(
    <div></div>
  )
};

export default withErrorContext(SomeComponent);
```

Now that React 16.8 has landed you can also do this more cleanly with hooks:

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
  const { setError } = useContext(ErrorContext)

  http.get("/blah").catch(() => setError(true))

  return <div />
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, I will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 1):

> ## Following the react context docs:
>
> I can create a provider like so :
>
> `class ProviderClass {
>       state = {
>           isError: false,
>           setError: (error) => {
>               this.state.isError = error;
>           }
>       }`

**I don't think so - there should be `setState` used.** There is a general rule in react "**don't mutate state - use setState()**" - abusing causes large part of react issues.

**I have a feeling you don't understand context role/usage.** This is more like a shortcut to global store eliminating the need of explicitly passing down props to childs through deep components structure (sometimes more than 10 levels).

> App > **CtxProvider** > Router > Other > .. > CtxConsumer > **ComponentConsumingCtxStorePropsNMethods**

**Accessing rendered DOM nodes with id** is used in some special cases, generally **should be avoided** because following renders will destroy any changes made externally.

**Use [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) if you need to render sth somewhere outside of main react app html node.**

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. When you say you don't think there should be a setError , i would ask you to read the React docs on the [ContextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component). Also I think you have misread my Question, I don't want to render outside the main react app, thats the problem. Unfortunately ReactDOM.render is placing the node outside the tree.

Comment: There shouldn't be `this.state.sth =` used in body of `setError`. You shouldn't have to use `ReactDOM.render` then - use HOC wherever you need.

Comment: You can also consume this context in many places, one centralized for display message and to have error methods access in the rest of them. This will be similiar to redux usage.